# Image/Gallery hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I am looking for an image hosting solution where:

1. I provide a user with a dedicated link
2. That user clicks it and lands on a gallery management page where they can upload and remove images

---

In addition, I want to show this user's gallery this way:

1. Based on the gallery ID or something, I embed some JavaScript code on my web page (so it loads at the visitors browser's run-time rather than web crawlers that eat bandwidth)
2. A visitor loads the page and sees the gallery. I will style it using my CSS.

---

The above solution frees me from bandwidth usage, file uploading coding, complicated API/REST calls and much more. The image files are not going through my server.
All I want is to be able to generate some unique "gallery-id", to which I will redirect one user (the "owner" of that gallery) as well as display it on a web page.

---

Any solution for the above?

NOT A DUPLICATE OF ANY OTHER QUESTION - please read the question.

Comment: @closetnoc did you read the question? Sure you didn't. Please don't shoot blindly..

Comment: Either way, this question would be on-hold because it is looking for a recommendation. I had a choice- a on-hold for requesting hosting (via the title) or asking for a recommendation in general (via the question). I do not do these things lightly. If I had not flagged it, it would have been put on-hold or marked as a duplicate anyway. It was just a matter of time.

Comment: And to support @closetnoc, I had already flagged this question as seeking an opinion based answer.  I do like that a brand new person with a score of 101 will suggest that the moderators are wrong.